# How do I properly set up a Silverlight-Enabled WCF Service?

Tags: vb.net, silverlight, wcf, web-services, interface

**EDIT**: I started a closed vote on this question because I resolved the issue. I was doing everything fine, but a reference to an ASP URL rewriter that I downloaded and uninstalled a while ago still had a reference in IIS.  This forum post by [Waclaw Stypula](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wcf/thread/e56a7768-b8a5-421e-98d9-5bd9f013bfee/) (the one with the steps) helped me track this down, by accident.  When I launched the run command, IIS told me that it (obviously) could not find the rewriter DLL.  I removed the reference and the app ran fine after that.

---

I am following the [silverlight.net](http://silverlight.net/learn/tutorials.aspx) tutorials by [Jesse Liberty](http://jesseliberty.com/). Currently I am trying to do [tutorial three](http://silverlight.net/learn/tutorials/sqldatagrid_vb.aspx), but I am running into a wall under the heading "**CREATE THE WEB SERVICE**" (about halfway down).

First, when I create the new service by adding it to the solution, the tutorial indicates that three files should be created; `IService1.vb`, `Service1.svc`, and `Service1.svc.vb`. I do not get the `IService1.vb` file when I add the service to the solution. I [downloaded](http://download.microsoft.com/download/f/a/9/fa9bafe9-3434-4af0-b428-d990bc9fbfaf/3-SQLDB_Source_VB.zip) the copy of the project they provided, and the `Service1.svc.vb` file is in there, so I added one manually and copied the contents of the file. The tutorial says it is a VB tutorial, but [displays C#](http://silverlight.net/themes/silverlight/images/learn/tutorials/Beta2SQLData_7.png) in the accompanying screenshot so maybe that is the issue.

After I get all the files made up like the tutorials (copy/paste to make sure I don't have a typo), I try to add the service reference and get the following error:

> `The service class of type KeyboardControl_Web.Service1 both defines a ServiceContract and inherits a ServiceContract from type KeyboardControl_Web.IService1. Contract inheritance can only be used among interface types.  If a class is marked with ServiceContractAttribute, it must be the only type in the hierarchy with ServiceContractAttribute.  Consider moving the ServiceContractAttribute on type KeyboardControl_Web.IService1 to a separate interface that type KeyboardControl_Web.IService1 implements.`

I tried googling different portions of the message, but did not find much useful information.

Here is the code for the different files:

```
//IService1.vb
Imports System.ServiceModel

' NOTE: If you change the class name "IService1" here, you must also update
'       the reference to "IService1" in Web.config.
<ServiceContract()> _
Public Interface IService1

    <OperationContract()> _
   Function GetAllLocations() As List(Of Address)

End Interface

//Service1.svc.vb
Imports Microsoft.VisualBasic
Imports System
Imports System.Collections.Generic
Imports System.Linq
Imports System.Runtime.Serialization
Imports System.ServiceModel
Imports System.Text

' NOTE: If you change the class name "Service1" here, you must also
'       update the reference to "Service1" in Web.config and in the
'       associated .svc file.

Public Class Service1
    Implements IService1
    Public Function GetAllLocations() As List(Of Address) Implements IService1.GetAllLocations
        Dim db As New DataClasses1DataContext()
        Dim matchingCustomers = From cust In db.userControlDemos Select cust
        'Return matchingCustomers.ToList()
    End Function
End Class
```

I am new to Silverlight/WCF in general, as well as to Interfaces and Services.  Can you guys help me get on the right track?

EDIT: I should add that I am using Visual Studio 2008, on Windows Vista Business SP1.

Answer (score 1):

if you have the Silverlight Tools for Visual Studio installed, instead of using the default WCF template, consider using the "Silverlight-enabled WCF Service" which simplifies things for you and puts all the required configuration in place.  This new template was introduced in Beta 2 and still exist (ref: http://timheuer.com/blog/archive/2008/06/06/changes-to-accessing-services-in-silverlight-2-beta-2.aspx).